# Icons change colour on Ubuntu 18.04 depending on window state

Tags: icons, themes

On Ubuntu 18.04 (running under VirtualBox), icons in the indicator bar change colour based on the state of the current window.

In the screenshot below, I have have a terminal window maximised and the icons are all the same colour.  The icons to the right are the default icons and the icon to the left belongs to one of my indicators.  The icon/colour scheme which I have used is ubuntu-mono-dark, which is what I believe the default icons are also using.

[image]

If I unmaximise the window, the default icons change colour:

[image]

To further muddy the waters, if I unmaximise the window and dock it with the top bar, the icons revert back to the same colour as my icon.  If the left navigation bar (dock) is set to never autohide and I dock the unmaximised window against the left navigation bar, again the icons revert back to the same colour as my icon.

Although I have determined from gsettings that the default theme is Ambiance, I cannot find the corresponding icon set for that theme (that is, I cannot see how/where there is a link between the theme of Ambiance and the icon set in use which is ubuntu-mono-dark).

Is the underlying mechanism such that when a window is unmaximised, a different theme or set of icons are selected?

If I create icons for that theme (place icons into the appropriate /usr/share/icons directory), will my icon will magically switch back and forth?

EDIT: Added screenshot of gnome tweaks tool running inside the VM:

[image]

Comment: To my eyes, the icon to the left (the man runnnig) is a different shade/colour to the icons to the right (which look to me to be ligher/whiter in colour).  I'll install gnome-tweaks and update soon...

Comment: It is an appindicator which I wrote (among others) called Indicator Script Runner: https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335

Answer (score 1):

there is only one color image in icons folder.
The difference you observe is because of panel property when in solid condition and in normal condition.

the panel is transparent when in normal condition and when it is solid its different color. those are specified in `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` file. you can make it solid all the time or give particular color in all cases. this is off-topic abut panel color now.

if you want to choose a particular icon for this "man running" icon,
below images are self explanatory.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Edit: 02nd Feb 04:30 UTC***

it seems that .svg image is filled with a color `#dfdbd2`

[image]

changing it to white color or any dark color will be the solution.

[image]

[image]

to change the fill color..
open the icon with text-editor

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what this panel property is that effects solid versus normal condition?  Is the property in gsettings or some artefact due to using SVG rather than PNG?

Comment: I don't follow your answer in terms of the icon.  Do I need to adjust my icon in some way, given the top panel switches from one state to another (transparency)?  I'd rather not play with the CSS file (particularly as it is generated) and I have many other indicators each with icons; I'd rather adjust each icon (assuming it would be the same fix for each).

Comment: Do you know where the icons for the network/volume/power are located?  If I can see how those are put together, maybe that might help me with my icons (I suspect/hope that I shouldn't need to touch the themes).